# How can I count distinct values of certain attributes within a date range?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to compute how many different types of fruit were sold in each county within a certain date range, using `county_name` and distinct `fruit_code`s.

I got a `county` table:

| county_code | county_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Colfax |
| 2 | Catron |
| 3 | Harding |

And I got a `fruit` table:

| county_code | fruit_code | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 3 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 4 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | 1 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | 2 | 2020-01-01 |
| 3 | 3 | 2020-01-01 |
| 1 | 1 | 2021-01-01 |
| 1 | 3 | 2021-01-01 |
| 2 | 2 | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | 2 | 2021-01-01 |
| 3 | 3 | 2021-01-01 |

So my expected result would be:

| county_name | fruit_code |
| --- | --- |
| Colfax | 4 |
| Catron | 2 |
| Harding | 3 |

I tried the following code, but the number of distinct `fruit_code`s is not exactly the correct one, unfortunately (note: the actual table is much longer, of course).

```
WITH unique_fruits AS (
    SELECT fruit_code FROM fruit
    WHERE date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-01-01'
    GROUP BY fruit_code HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT county_code) = 1
)
SELECT c.county_name, COUNT(*) AS no_of_unique_fruits
  FROM fruit AS f
  JOIN county AS c
    ON f.county_code = c.county_code
   AND f.fruit_code IN (SELECT fruit_code FROM unique_fruits)
GROUP BY c.county_name
ORDER BY no_of_unique_fruits DESC
```

What have I forgotten here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a `LEFT` join of `county` to `fruit` (so that you get a result with `0` for counties that do not meet the conditions) and group by county.
Also, the condition about the date should be placed in the `ON` clause:

```
SELECT c.county_name,
       COUNT(DISTINCT f.fruit_code) total
FROM county c LEFT JOIN fruit f
ON f.county_code = c.county_code AND date BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-01-01'
GROUP BY c.county_code;
```

I assume that `county_code` is the primary key of `county`.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1dfdd6d11714599f1f9f152e19aa7746).

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this easier

> ```
> WITH fruitcodespercountry AS(
> SELECT "county_code", COUNT(DISTINCT "fruit_code") fruit_code
> FROM Fruit WHERE "date" BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2021-01-01'
> GROUP  BY "county_code")
> SELECT "county_name" ,fruit_code FROM fruitcodespercountry f JOIN country c ON f."county_code" = c."county_code"
> ```
>
> ```
> county_name | fruit_code
> :---------- | ---------:
> Colfax      |          4
> Catron      |          2
> Harding     |          3
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=ca0c5e32fa74d6c1afd16cf7cb8fe32d)*